# G-d was Got, why do we say it?

Tags: names

The term, "God/G-d" came from Norse mythology, it meant "Got," a god of their faith. I am honestly ignorant of why the Judaic faith applies it today.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the word G-d (and also G-tt in German, etc.) comes from and Indo-European word meaning "to invoke", "libate", or "pour". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%C7%B5%CA%B0ut%C3%B3s

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/the-origin-of-the-word-god

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea. Can you clarify what precisely your question is? What do you mean by "the Judaic faith applies it today"? Do you mean to ask why any Jew would ever use the word "God" if the word stemmed from another religion? If so, do you have any reason to believe that there would be an issue using such a word, when clearly now it simply means the Deity?

Comment: @Alex My question indeed way "why any Jew would ever use the word "God" if the word stemmed from another religion?" The problem is, it'll be like using the name Jesus since that name also means deity to the christians and so forth. I think it best if we'd just call Elohim HaShem.

Comment: @user17072 But "Jesus" does not mean the Deity in general. "God" does. Regardless of what the words may have meant in the ancient past, or where they came from.

Comment: Hellenistic Jews also referred to God as "Zeus." See [Letter of Aristeas](http://www.ccel.org/c/charles/otpseudepig/aristeas.htm) (15), also quoted by Josephus somewhere

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find "Got" on online lists of Norse deities; not that that's a proof he wasn't one.

Moreover, [the etymology of *god*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/god) to a reconstructed [PIE](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language#Historical_and_geographical_setting) root seems likely to predate it to [Norse religion](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse_religion#Historical_development).

But none of that answers your question, which was "why the Judaic faith applies it today". Well, it's because *God* means "the deity", and **[not](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)** "some Norse deity named Got".

Comment: you are correct how we today, or at least, when we say G-d we are not bearing in mind the Norse deity named Got.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_(word)):

> The English word ***God*** continues the Old English *God* (guþ, gudis in Gothic, *gud in modern Scandinavian, *God* in Frisian and Dutch, and *Gott* in modern German), which is derived from Proto-Germanic *ǥuđán.

The article continues and says that the Proto-Germanic word *ǥuđán most likely comes from the root which  means to libate or pour, or possibly from the root meaning to call or invoke.

The word has nothing to do with Norse mythology at all.

Comment: some think it does do with Norse mythology, as so the name G-d comes from the pagan god named Got.

Comment: @user17072 I have been unable to trace _any_ pagan god named Got. Could you point it out to me please?

Comment: @user17072 "some think it does do with Norse mythology" Why would it matter what 'some' think? There are enough people in the world that if we accounted for every crazy idea 'some people thought up, we'd never be able to do anything! One might have an argument if there was a 'mainstream' world opinion, but I think that the answers here show that this isn't such a well accepted idea.

Answer (score 0):

"G-d" is the standard English-language term for a deity, regardless of its linguistic origins. The "Ba'al Shem Tov" was unconcerned that this Hebrew term for "master" was also applied to "Ba'al Peor" of avodah zarah fame.

In the same vein, Arabic-speaking Jews, when not praying, will usually refer to the deity  as "Allah", it's just the Arabic term for deity, despite its association with Islam (https://www.quora.com/Do-Arab-Jews-say-Allah)